# What is an assembly-level representation of pushl/popl %esp?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-memory, instruction-set, stack-pointer

I'm trying to understand the behavior of pushing and popping the stack pointer register.  In AT&T:

```
pushl %esp
```

and

```
popl %esp
```

Note that they store the computed value back into `%esp`.

I'm considering these instructions independently, not in sequence. I know that the value stored in `%esp` is always the value before the increment/decrement, but how could I represent the behavior in assembly language? This is what I've come up with so far.

For `pushl %esp` (ignoring FLAGS and the effect on the temporary register):

```
movl %esp, %edx     1. save value of %esp
subl  $4, %esp      2. decrement stack pointer
movl %edx, (%esp)   3. store old value of %esp on top of stack
```

For `popl %esp`:

```
movl (%esp), %esp   You wouldn’t need the increment portion.
```

Is this correct? If not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've been coding in x86 assembler for decades. I've never had any occasion to use these.    I'm sure they are defined, but does it really matter in practice?

Comment: No, my textbook mentions it's never used in practice, but it's a good exercise to understand the instruction convention.

Comment: Could be. But I'd spend my time thinking about instructions like "enter", "leave", "cmpsd",  "lea", all of which do apparantly odd things that are pretty useful in the right circumstances.

Comment: `pushl %esp` is potentially useful when you want to pass a pointer to a stack buffer to a function with a stack-args calling convention.  e.g. you might use `sub $8, %esp` / `push %esp` / `push $fmt` / `call scanf` to read a `double` from stdin in 32-bit code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it says about `push esp` in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Developer's Manual: Combined Volumes](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html) (actually in vol.2, or HTML scrape at https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push):

> The PUSH ESP instruction pushes the value of the ESP register as it existed
> before the instruction was executed. If a PUSH instruction uses a memory operand
> in which the ESP register is used for computing the operand address, the address
> of the operand is computed before the ESP register is decremented.

And as regards to `pop esp` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop):

> The POP ESP instruction increments the stack pointer (ESP) before data at the old
> top of stack is written into the destination.

and `pop 16(%esp)`

> If the ESP register is used as a base register for addressing a destination operand in memory, the POP instruction computes the effective address of the operand **after it increments** the ESP register.

So yes, your pseudo-code is correct except for modifying FLAGS and `%edx`.

Comment: Ok, thanks nrz. Would you say the assembly-behavior I wrote is correct?

Comment: @amorimluc Your code looks correct to me, as it matches the Intel documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those sequences are correct except for the effect on FLAGS, and of course `push %esp` doesn't clobber `%edx`.  Instead, imagine an internal temporary<sup>1</sup> if you want to break it down into separate steps, instead of thinking of a `push` primitive operation which snapshots its input (source operand) before doing anything else.

(Similarly `pop DST` can be modeled as `pop %temp` / `mov %temp, DST`, with all effects of pop finished before it evaluates and writes to the destination, even if that is or involves the stack pointer.)

#### `push` equivalents that work even in the ESP special cases

(In all of these, I'm assuming 32-bit compat or protected mode with SS configured normally, with stack address size matching the mode, if it's even possible for that not to be the case.  The 64-bit mode equivalent with `%rsp` works the same way with `-8` / `+8`.  16-bit mode doesn't allow `(%sp)` addressing modes so you'd have to consider this as pseudo-code.)

```
#push SRC         for any source operand including %esp or 1234(%esp)
   mov  SRC, %temp
   lea  -4(%esp), %esp         # esp-=4 without touching FLAGS
   mov  %temp, (%esp)
```

i.e. `mov SRC, %temp` ; `push %temp`
Or since we're describing an uninterruptible transaction anyway (a single `push` instruction),
we [don't need to move ESP before storing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258402/is-it-valid-to-write-below-esp):

```
#push %REG              # or immediate, but not memory source
   mov  %REG, -4(%esp)
   lea  -4(%esp), %esp
```

(This simpler version wouldn't assemble for real with a memory source, only register or immediate, as well as being unsafe if an interrupt or signal handler runs between the mov and the LEA.  In real assembly, `mov mem, mem` with two explicit addressing modes isn't encodeable, but `push (%eax)` is because the memory destination is implicit.  You could consider it as pseudo-code even for a memory source.  But snapshotting in a temporary is a more realistic model of what happens internally, like the first block or like `mov SRC, %temp` / `push %temp`.)

If you're talking about actually using such a sequence in a real program, I don't think there's a way to *exactly* duplicate `push %esp` without a temporary register (first version), or (second version) disabling interrupts or having an ABI with a red-zone. (Like x86-64 System V for non-kernel code, so you could duplicate `push %rsp`.)

#### `pop` equivalents:

```
#pop DST   works for any operand
  mov  (%esp), %temp
  lea  4(%esp), %esp      # esp += 4 without touching FLAGS
  mov  %temp, DST         # even if DST is %esp or 1234(%esp)
```

i.e. `pop %temp` / `mov %temp, DST`.  That accurately reflects the case where `DST` is a memory addressing mode that involves ESP: the value of ESP *after* the increment is used.  I verified Intel's docs for this with `push $5` ; `pop -8(%esp)`.  That copied the dword `5` to the dword right below the one written by `push` when I single-stepped it in GDB on a Skylake CPU.  If `-8(%esp)` address calculation had happened using ESP before that instruction executed, there would have been a 4-byte gap.

In the special case of `pop %esp`, yes that steps on the increment, simplifying to:

```
#pop %esp  # 3 uops on Skylake, 1 byte
   mov  (%esp), %esp             # 1 uop on Skylake.  3 bytes of machine-code size
```

---

#### Intel manuals have misleading pseudocode

Intel's pseudocode in the Operation sections of their instruction-set manual entries (SDM vol.2) do *not* accurately reflect the stack-pointer special cases.  Only the extra paragraphs in the Description sections (quoted in [@nrz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968824/what-is-an-assembly-level-representation-of-pushl-popl-esp/14969137#14969137)) get that right.

https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop shows (for StackAddrSize = 32 and OperandSize = 32) a load into DEST and *then* incrementing ESP

```
     DEST ← SS:ESP; (* Copy a doubleword *)
     ESP ← ESP + 4;
```

But that's misleading for `pop %esp` because it implies that ESP += 4 happens after ESP = load(SS:ESP).  Correct pseudo-code would use

```
 if ... operand size etc.
     TEMP ← SS:ESP; (* Copy a doubleword *)
     ESP ← ESP + 4;

 ..
 // after all the if / else size blocks:
 DEST ← TEMP
```

Intel gets this right for other instructions like [`pshufb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufb#operation) where the pseudo-code starts out with `TEMP ← DEST` to snapshot the original state of the read-write destination operand.

Similarly, https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push#operation shows RSP being decremented first, not showing the `src` operand being snapshotted before that.  Only the extra paragraphs in the text Description section correctly handle that special case.

---

[**AMD's manual** Volume 3:
General-Purpose and
System Instructions (March 2021)](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf#page=315) is similarly wrong about this (my emphasis):

> Copies the value pointed to by the stack pointer (SS:rSP) to the specified register or memory location
> **and then** increments the rSP by 2 for a 16-bit pop, 4 for a 32-bit pop, or 8 for a 64-bit pop.

Unlike Intel, it doesn't even document the special cases of popping into the stack pointer itself or with a memory operand involving rSP.  At least not here, and a search on `push rsp` or `push esp` didn't find anything.

(AMD uses `rSP` to mean SP / ESP / RSP depending on current stack-size attribute selected by SS.)

AMD doesn't have a pseudocode section like Intel does, at least not for supposedly simple instructions like push/pop.  (There is one for `pusha`.)

---

**Footnote 1**: That could even be what happens on some CPUs (although I don't think so).  For example on Skylake, [Agner Fog measured](https://agner.org/optimize/) `push %esp` as 2 uops for the front-end vs. 1 micro-fused store for pushing any other register.

We do know that Intel CPUs do have some registers that get renamed like the architectural registers, but which are only accessible by microcode. e.g. https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/ mentions "some extra architectural registers for internal use."  So `mov %esp, %temp` / `push %temp` could in theory be how it decoded.

**But a more likely explanation** is that the extra measured uops in a long *sequence* of `push %esp` instructions are just **stack-sync uops**, like we get any time the OoO back-end explicitly reads ESP after a push/pop operation.  e.g. `push %eax` / `mov %esp, %edx` would also cause a stack-sync uop.  (The "[stack engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture)" is what avoids needing an extra uop for the `esp -= 4` part of `push`)

`push %esp` is sometimes useful, e.g. to push the address of some stack space you just reserved:

```
  sub   $8, %esp
  push  %esp
  push  $fmt         # "%lf"
  call  scanf
  movsd 8(%esp), %xmm0

  # add $8, %esp    # balance out the pushes at some point, or just keep using that allocated space for something.  Or clean it up just before returning along with the space for your local var.
```

`pop %esp` costs 3 uops on Skylake, one load (p23) and two ALU for any integer ALU port (2p0156).  So it's even less efficient, but it has basically no use-cases.  You can't usefully save/restore the stack pointer on the stack; if you know how to get to where you saved it, you can just restore it with `add`.

Comment: I don't understand a specific comment you made. You say `mov  %REG, -4(%esp)` wouldn't work in "real assembly". Why not? I just tested, and something like `movl %esp, -4(%esp)` works just fine. Please clarify. Thanks! (Full disclosure: I am just learning assembly as we speak, and from the same book as the OP. I would have rewritten `pushl` exactly as you suggested as "pseudocode", thinking it would actually work - and I believe it actually does.)

Comment: @mathguy: Data below ESP can be clobbered asynchronously, in ABIs without a red-zone.  [Is it valid to write below ESP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52258402)  *Usually* it's fine, in fact in user-space only a signal handler (Linux) or SEH (Windows) can clobber it, or if you're stopped with a debugger and use `print foo()` to make the debugger run a function  in your process using your process's stack.  That's why I said *since we're describing an uninterruptible transaction*, because `mov %REG, -4(%esp)` leaves the data vulnerable until ESP moves.

Comment: OK - that explains why one shouldn't replicate `pushl` in that manner (and at some point I will understand what you explained). But what confused me was the very general statement that something like `movl %reg, mem` isn't "encodeable". Perhaps I am confused by the word "encodeable" - I took it to mean "valid" or "allowed". It seems to be "valid" and "allowed" (even if, as you say, not advisable in some situations).

Comment: @mathguy: But I think you're asking about the paragraph in parens with *In real assembly, `mov mem, mem` with two explicit addressing modes isn't encodeable*.  I edited to clarify the point of that; its explaining why that simpler block wouldn't assemble as a replacement for `pushl (%eax)` or other memory-source push, only register or immediate.  `movl (%eax), -4(%esp)` is not something x86 machine code can express.

Comment: OK, got it - we were writing at the same time.

Comment: @mathguy: Yeah, took me a minute to go back and re-read my answer from a month ago to figure out what I'd been talking about myself; not surprised it wasn't clear to someone else, especially a beginner who didn't already know the stuff I was writing about.  :P