# Stack Pointer in Assembly. ESP points always empty space or not?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-memory, stack-pointer

Initially, ESP refers to the empty space of memory.

**When I push something such as push 1, then it will refers to the memory location of 1, or next empty space?**

here is the example

```
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
/*
---------
(empty space)    <- esp, ebp
---------
ebp     (initially stack pointer was here)
---------
*/
```

**Another question is that when I make an empty stack space, which point ESP will points?**

Here is the example: (each memory location is 4 bytes)

```
/*
  --------
1        <- initial esp
  --------
*/
sub esp, 12
; now esp points to this one 
/*
  --------
4          <- esp
  --------
3
  --------
2  
  --------
1        
  --------
*/
; or this one
/*
  --------
3           <- esp
  --------
2  
  --------
1        
  --------
*/
```

Assume that numbers are the memory location addresses

Answer (score 4):

The Operation section in the manual (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push) shows that push modifies ESP *before* storing to `[ESP]`.

```
            ESP ← ESP – 4;
            Memory[SS:ESP] ← SRC;
                (* push dword *)
```

`pop` does the reverse: load from `[ESP]` and then modify ESP.

Like many other ISAs (e.g. ARM), x86 uses a "full" stack where the stack pointer normally points to the last thing pushed, not to empty space below it.

---

Fun fact: `pop esp` overwrites ESP *after* incrementing, so it's like `mov esp, [esp]`.
`push esp` reads the value to be stored *before* decrementing ESP.  Intel's manual entries document this, but their pseudocode doesn't match.  See [What is an assembly-level representation of pushl/popl %esp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968824/what-is-an-assembly-level-representation-of-pushl-popl-esp/69489798#69489798) for proper push/pop pseudocode that works for all cases, even `push esp` and `pop esp`.

---

re: part2: `add esp, 12` moves ESP by 12 bytes, or 12B/4B = 3 "stack slots".  1+3 = 4.

Comment: what about last question? sub esp, 12