# Can a “PUSH” instruction's operation be performed using other instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, stack-memory, instruction-set

It currently seems to me that the only reason we have instructions like “Push” is to replace multiple MOV, and arithmetic instructions with a single instruction.

Is there anything “PUSH” does that cannot be accomplished by more primitive instructions?

Is “PUSH” just a single Mnemonic that compiles into multiple machine code instructions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Push is a real machine instruction (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push) *not* just an assembler macro / pseudo-instruction.  For example, `push rax` has a single-byte encoding of `0x50`.

But yes you can emulate it using other instructions like `sub rsp, 8` and a `mov` store.  (**This is normal for a CISC machine like x86!**)  e.g. see [What is the function of the push / pop instructions used on registers in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584089/what-is-the-function-of-the-push-pop-instructions-used-on-registers-in-x86-ass/39339435#39339435)

To emulate it exactly (without modifying flags), you use LEA instead of ADD/SUB.

```
  lea   rsp, [rsp-8]
  mov   qword [rsp], 123      ; push 123 in 64-bit mode
```

See also [What is an assembly-level representation of pushl/popl %esp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968824/what-is-an-assembly-level-representation-of-pushl-popl-esp/69489798#69489798) for equivalent instructions that match the behaviour even for `push rsp` / `pop rsp`, push/pop `[rsp+16]`, as well as for any other operand (immediate, reg, or mem).

---

> Is there anything “PUSH” does that cannot be accomplished by more primitive instructions?

Nothing significant beyond efficiency and code-size.

Single instructions are atomic wrt. interrupts - they either happen or they don't. This is normally totally irrelevant; asynchronous interrupts don't usually look at the stack / register contents of the code that got interrupted.

PUSH can get the job done in a single byte of machine code for pushing a single register, or 2 bytes for a small immediate.  A multi-instruction sequence is much larger.  The architect of 8086's ISA was very focused on making small code-size possible, so yes **it's totally normal to have an instruction that replaces a couple longer instructions with one short one.**  e.g. we have `not` instead of having to use `xor reg, -1`, and `inc` instead of `add reg, 1`.  (Although again those both have different FLAGS semantics, with NOT leaving flags untouched and INC/DEC leaving CF untouched.)  Not to mention all of x86's other special-case encodings, like 1-byte encodings for xchg-with-[e/r]ax.  See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code

Also efficiency: PUSH decodes to a single uop (in the fused domain) on Pentium-M and later CPUs, thanks to the stack engine that handles implicit uses of the stack pointer by instructions like push/pop and call/ret.  2 separate instructions of course decode to at least 2 uops.  (Except the special case of macro-fusion of test/cmp + JCC).

On ancient P5 Pentium, emulating push with separate ALU and `mov` instructions was actually a win - before PPro CPUs didn't know how to break down complex CISC instructions into separate uops, and complex instructions couldn't pair in P5's dual-issue in-order pipeline.  (See [Agner Fog's microarch guide](https://agner.org/optimize/).)  The main benefit here was being able to mix in other instructions that could pair, and to only do one big `sub` and then just the `mov` stores instead of multiple changes to the stack pointer.

This also applies to early P6-family before the stack engine.  GCC with `-march=pentium3` for example will tend to avoid `push` and just do one bigger adjustment to ESP.

Comment: Couldn’t of asked for a better answer! Very helpful

Comment: @Tyler: I was going to close it as a duplicate of [What is the function of the push / pop instructions used on registers in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39339435), but then I noticed you ask if there was *anything* that can't be accomplished without it.  And that turned out to be interesting enough to think about that I wanted to answer,  The only thing I could think of besides efficiency / code-size is atomicity wrt. interrupts.  But I like talking about efficiency so that works too. :P